# Appear #VALUE! in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I faced this problem. When I want to retrieve the value in a cell with the value of #VALUE!, I got the error2015. May I know how to solve this kind of problem with some example? Thanks so much.

Comment: what is the cause of the error? A formula or a function? Can you provide any code?

Comment: =IF(OR(RC[-40]="",RC[-14]<>""),"",FirstMissingDate(RC[-40],  IF( OR(LEFT(RC[5],3)="LON", LEFT(RC[5],3)="FIX", LEFT(RC[5],3)="RTP"),IF(RC[-33]>R4C45,RC[-33], R4C45),RC[-33])   ))

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem. The cell actually contains a `Variant/Error`, so there you have it.

The same value you can get by calling `CVErr(2015)`.

You might use the `.Text` property instead of `.Value` to get the actual text '#VALUE!', but then a) you will not be able to know if it's an error or someone just put mere text '#VALUE!' in the cell, and b) the returned text will be different in different regional versions of Excel.

If you are checking cells for errors, the right thing to do is to call `IsError(.Value)`, and if `True`, check exactly which error.

Comment: Since you have covered `.Text` in your post now with an explanation, I am removing my post :)